# What is the appropriate mechanism for finding administrative support for a conference?

Tags: conference, etiquette, administration

We're organizing a conference and I currently don't have administrative support to process our income and receipts. I don't have a personal admin and I curious about the best and polite way to find support without pressuring someone into the role.

Comment: A little bit more context could help: specifically, who's "we"? However, I suspect the answer is probably to contact the administrative staff of the institute / department you're formally operating under and ask them what to do.

Comment: We = a bunch of graduate students.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to think about whether you need a full-time administrative assistant for that, or maybe students could take over some of these tasks. It probably depends on the size of the conference also. But I generally found that students are very well willing to take over such tasks, because it allows them a little bit to peek behind the curtains of conference organization.

An important question when engaging students is whether you have funds available to support the conference organization. If yes, then I think it should be easy to find students willing to help for a small salary. Otherwise you would have to rely on volunteering, which may be more difficult.

Comment: To address @iilmari's comments, we are already volunteering students. Good suggestion regardless.